# How do I know when what I should store in my external to /etc configurations in etckeeper?

Tags: configuration, version-control, etckeeper

I read about the [ability to store configuration files](https://serverfault.com/questions/211425/can-etckeeper-be-used-to-track-config-files-outside-of-etc) that live outside of `/etc` here, and I tested it out on a test server, and it appears to work.

One thing that I'm having a bit of an issue with however, is identifying what of these files external to `/etc` in an application needs to be included and what needs to be left out.  What makes a file a good candidate for inclusion or exclusion in etckeeper?

It seems to me that if you have an application that sits at the top of a LAMP or other stack, that it's configuration file and `.htaccess` or equivalent should be included in `/etc` to have a log of changes that can be included in the same commit.

While I know you could conceivably store the entire application in git, it slows down commits, and mis-uses git.

It also seems that anything considered cache or binary should be excluded, but that any text-based configuration files should be included.

Comment: If nobody can answer my question, can someone with a higher rep move this to the Ubuntu Stackexchange?